# PngComponents: how to add PNG file to TPngImageList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm tryin to add PNG file to TPngImageList (PngComponents for D7 got from http://code.google.com/p/cubicexplorer/downloads/list ).

```
type
  TImgListCrack = class(TPngImageList);

function LoadPngIconEx(ImageList: TPngImageList; const fn: string): boolean;
var
  Icon: HICON;
  AImage: TPngObject;
begin
  with ImageList do
  begin
    BeginUpdate;
    try
      AImage:= TPngObject.Create;
      AImage.LoadFromFile(fn);
      Icon:= TImgListCrack(ImageList).PngToIcon(AImage);
      ImageList_AddIcon(Handle, Icon);
      DestroyIcon(Icon);
      FreeAndNil(AImage);
      Result:= true;
    finally
      EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

result: icon not added, imagelist still empty. How to do it ok?

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but shouldn't that simply work?

```
ImageList.PngImages.Add.PngImage.LoadFromFile(fn);
```

Comment: no it doesn't. No property Items in TPngImageList, no method Add w/out params.

Comment: Indeed, that was for TPngImageCollection. Changed the code for TPngImageList.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using other methods of PngImageList. Prop PngImages has needed function.

```
function LoadPngIconEx(ImageList: TPngImageList; const fn: string): boolean;
var
  AImage: TPngObject;
begin
  if not FileExists(fn) then
    Result:= false
  else
  begin
    AImage:= TPngObject.Create;
    try
      AImage.LoadFromFile(fn);
      ImageList.PngImages.Add.PngImage:= AImage;
      Result:= true;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(AImage);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: An answer with just code is not a good answer here on Stack Overflow. Please add some sentences explaining what it is about this code that answers the question. What was wrong with the original code, and why does this fix it?